# gzip url request in python

Tags: url, python-requests, gzip

I am using python with requests module to fetch data from api with a json feed.
When I include the request for gzip as the encoding I am not seeing any change. Am I implementing it the wrong way here?

```
my_headers = {'accept-encoding':'gzip'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=my_headers)
print(response.headers)
print(len(response.content))
```

The response headers always come back with

```
'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
```

but this happens with or without the inclusion of my request headers, the length and load times do not change either

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Requests: HTTP for Humans - Binary Response Content](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content)

> gzip and deflate transfer-encodings are automatically decoded for you.

Comment: Updated link: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content (cannot edit the original answer)